# Dump of a mysql table on import replaced existing records

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, import

I took a dump using mysqldump..

```
mysqldump -u... -p... mydb t1 > mydb_table.sql
```

Then I imported the dump in another database having same table, but different records..

```
mysql -u...-p... mydb < mydb_tables.sql
```

The importing db had records from primary_key 1 to 1000, and the exporting db had 5000 to 10,000..

But on import the existing records, ie 1 to 1000 got deleted..

**How?? Why?? If it a default behaviour, what options I can give to dump to not let it happen next time..**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The mysqldump, by default, will drop the table. You should specified the `--no-create-info` option like this:

```
mysqldump -u... -p... --no-create-info --skip-extended-insert mydb t1 > mydb_table.sql
```

That way, you only have inserts to deal with. Using `--skip-extended-insert` will insert one row at a time. This help deal with duplicate issues, but you will have import like this:

```
mysql -u...-p... --force mydb < mydb_tables.sql
```

The `--force` option is for the sole purpose of continuing INSERTs in the event a duplicate key is encountered. In that instance, the offending INSERT's error is ignored and on to the next INSERT.

Comment: is it possible to retrive the data which is deleted during the dump?